# How to save data of text area in php

Tags: php, html, sql, textbox, textarea

[image]I'm a PHP learner. I have a website built on PHP. On the front end of one of our website pages there are four tabs. See the pic below for reference -

[image]

I want to add one more tab here. There should be a simple option of adding content in the admin panel for this tab (Which I have accomplished)

My problem is, when I am adding content to the text area in admin panel and hitting submit, the content disappears. I guess the content is not being stored in the database. I checked the SQL file made the possible changes. Although I'm not sure if I did it right. But I'm quite sure that there's a very small lag here which I am not able to figure out.

P.S. Check the screenshot of admin panel for more clarification about my issue.

The text area with heading **Table of Contents - Simple** is the one which I added. But as I mentioned, even if add content here and hit submit it becomes blank.

Below is the code of the page in screenshot -

```
"<?php
require_once '../config/config.php';
require_once '../class/dbclass.php';
require_once 'class/content.php';
require_once 'class/category.php';
require_once 'class/common.php';
require './isLogin.php';

$content = new Content();

$category = new Category();enter code here
$catList = $category->fetchCategoryTree();
//echo '<pre>';
//print_r($catList);
//echo '</pre>';
//exit;

//$catParentList = $category->fetchParentCategory(30);

//echo '<pre>';
//print_r($catParentList);
//echo '</pre>';

//echo implode("->",$catParentList);
//echo '<pre>';
//print_r(array_reverse($catParentList));
//echo '</pre>';

//exit;

$cat_id = 0;
$title = '';
$price = '';
$description = '';
$descriptions = '';
$author = $published = $report_code = '';

$content_id = isset($_REQUEST['id']) && $_REQUEST['id'] != "" ? $_REQUEST['id'] : 0;
//$category_list = $category->getAllCategory();
if ($content_id) {
    $contentData = $content->getContentById($content_id);
    $cat_id = isset($contentData[0]['cat_id']) ? $contentData[0]['cat_id'] : '';
    $title = isset($contentData[0]['title']) ? $contentData[0]['title'] : '';
    $price = isset($contentData[0]['price']) ? $contentData[0]['price'] : '';
    $description = isset($contentData[0]['description']) ? $contentData[0]['description'] : '';
    $descriptions = isset($contentData[0]['descriptions']) ? $contentData[0]['descriptions'] : '';
    $report_code = isset($contentData[0]['report_code']) ? $contentData[0]['report_code'] : '';
    $published = isset($contentData[0]['published']) ? $contentData[0]['published'] : '';
    $author = isset($contentData[0]['author']) ? $contentData[0]['author'] : '';

}

if($content_id == 0)
    $pageName = "Add Report";
else
    $pageName = "Edit Report";
?>
<?php require_once './includes/header.php'; ?>
<?php require_once './includes/sidebar.php'; ?>

      <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <section class="content-header">
          <h1>
              <b><?php echo $pageName; ?></b>
          </h1>
          <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="<?php echo ADMIN_ROOT ?>dashboard.php"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
            <li class="active"><?php echo $pageName; ?></li>
          </ol>
        </section>

        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">
          <div class="row">
            <!-- left column -->
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <!-- general form elements -->
                <div class="box box-primary">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['error_message']) && $_SESSION['error_message'] != ''): ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
                        <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
                        <?php echo $_SESSION['error_message']; ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['success_message']) && $_SESSION['success_message'] != ''): ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
                            <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
                            <?php echo $_SESSION['success_message']; ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['info_message']) && $_SESSION['info_message'] != ''): ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable">
                            <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
                            <?php echo $_SESSION['info_message']; ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?> 

                </div><!-- /.box-header -->

                <!-- form start -->
               <form id="content-form" action="models/contentProcess.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" novalidate> 
                    <div class="box-body">

                        <input type="hidden" name="type" value="<?php echo ($content_id == 0) ? "addContent" : "editContent"; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="content_id" id="content_id" value="<?php echo $content_id ?>">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Select Category</label> 
                            <select id="cat_id" name="cat_id" class="form-control">
                                <?php foreach ($catList as $cl) { ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $cl["id"] ?>"  <?php echo ($cl["id"] == $cat_id) ? 'selected' : '' ; ?> ><?php echo $cl["name"]; ?></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Title</label> 
                            <input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Enter title" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $title ?>">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Report Code</label> 
                            <input type="text" name="report_code" id="report_code" placeholder="Enter Report Code" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $report_code ?>">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Image</label> 
                            <input type="file" class="btn btn-default btn-file" name="image" id="image">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Published</label> 
                            <input type="text" name="published" id="published" placeholder="Enter published" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $published ?>">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Author</label> 
                            <input type="text" name="author" id="author" placeholder="Enter author" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $author ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Price</label> 
                            <input type="text" name="price" id="price" placeholder="Enter price" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $price ?>">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Description</label> 
                            <textarea id="description" name="description" class="form-control" rows="10" cols="80">
                                <?php echo $description; ?>
                            </textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Table of Contents - Simple</label> 
                            <textarea id="descriptions" name="descriptions" class="form-control" rows="15" cols="100">
                                <?php echo $descriptions; ?>
                            </textarea>
                        </div>

                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="submitform">Submit</button>
                        <a href="<?php echo ADMIN_ROOT; ?>contentList.php" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
              </div><!-- /.box -->

            </div><!--/.col (left) -->
            <!-- right column -->

          </div>   <!-- /.row -->
        </section><!-- /.content -->
      </div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->
<?php require_once './includes/footer.php'; ?>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo ADMIN_ROOT; ?>plugins/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace('descriptions',{
        //uiColor:"#532F12",
        toolbar: 'MyToolbar',

    });
</script>
<script language="javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace('description',{
        //uiColor:"#532F12",
        toolbar: 'MyToolbar',
    });
</script>"

    Code snippet of reportDetail.php
<div class="tab-content" style="min-height:775px;">
                                        <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane <?php if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) { ?>active<?php } ?>" style="overflow: auto;<?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && $_SESSION['user_id'] > 0) { ?>max-height: 1520px;<?php } else { ?> height: 795px;<?php } ?>">
                                            <?= $contentData['description'] ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade <?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && $_SESSION['user_id'] > 0) { ?>active in<?php } ?>" style="overflow: auto;<?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && $_SESSION['user_id'] > 0) { ?>max-height: 1520px;<?php } else { ?> height: 795px;<?php } ?>">
                                            <?= $contentData['descriptions'] ?>
                                        </div>

                                        <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade <?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && $_SESSION['user_id'] > 0) { ?>active in1<?php } ?>" >
```

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question. Hope it will provide clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html:-

```
<form action="" method="post">
<textarea name="textarea" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

php:-

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{   
  $yourtextarea= $_POST["textarea"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Shoyeb. Could you please tell me where should I put this code?

Comment: It will be good if you provide your php code for that particular page.

Comment: Dear Shoyeb, I have added the code in the question. Kindly review it.

Comment: Hi Zubair, this is actually the html, I need to see the php code, where you are storing the value in database and the form submit event in php, if thats not possible just var_dump($descriptions); and see if that shows anything. You gotta debug your code yourself.

Comment: Looks fine, check if value is getting inserted in database table, provide code where you are trying to insert/update data in a table.

Comment: I hope the database table you are talking about is the one which is in the PHPMyAdmin

Comment: Yes but I am not asking for a database or table, I am asking for php code where you are trying to insert/update data.

Comment: Content of these text area will be displayed here - https://www.kbvresearch.com/reportDetail.php?content_id=global-automotive-biometric-access-system-market--2016-_-2022

Under the Table of Contents Tab. 

Do you want me to share the reportDetail.php file's code?

Comment: The url I shared is just an example. Basically, it is a report page and we have a lot of reports which appears under slug reportDetail.php

Comment: You will notice that Table of Contents tab is empty. Which is the problem.

Comment: Done Shoyeb! Kindly review.

Comment: Again thats not what I want, I want to see the php code where you are inserting data in the database or updating data in the database. The php code for mysql insert/update and the insert/update query.

Comment: Please check the code here https://github.com/zubairabbas/sql-code-kbv/wiki

Comment: I see the problem is in your php code for mysql queries.

Comment: I would be thankful to you if you could help me fix this Shoyeb.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get you. Which PHP file are you talking about?

Comment: Select query to get report data from database, you write sql queries in php to get database values in php variable. Then you fetch data.

Comment: I am not sure if I'm still able to understand you properly. Should I send you screenshot of PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: OKay, I think I got you now. Here it's - 

'<?php

class Content extends MySQLCN {

    function getRecentContentTitle() {
        $sql = "SELECT content_id, title FROM `content` WHERE status = '1' AND isupcoming = 0 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 5";
        $result = $this->select_assoc($sql);
        return $result;
    }'

Comment: Here you are only selecting two columns content_id and title, where are you selecting descriptions column in sql query? I need that code.

Comment: I am overwhelmed with your response Shoyeb. Let me explore the files to get you the code you are asking for.

Comment: Please check this - https://github.com/zubairabbas/help-kbv/blob/master/class/content.php

Comment: This is what I needed, now look for two functions addContent and editContent, include descriptions column in Insert query in addContent and include  descriptions column in Update query in editContent. If you are not inserting descriptions column in table how will you see the data?

Comment: This is called debugging.

Comment: Shoyeb bhai, I have made the changes on the file - https://github.com/zubairabbas/help-kbv/blob/master/class/content.php

You will find the new code when you will scroll down.

Comment: But now, when I click on submit, I receive this message - 

Update Operation Failed..
Unknown column 'descriptions' in 'field list'

Comment: That is obvious you made a mistake

Comment: Ahh, what's that now :( Please tell!

Comment: In addContent function,  make edit as follows,  $sql = "INSERT INTO content (`cat_id`,`title`,`description`,`descriptions`,`status`,`created_at`, `price`, `published`, `author`, `report_code`)
                VALUES('{$data['cat_id']}','{$data['title']}','{$data['description']}','{$data['descriptions']}','1',NOW(), '{$data['price']}', '{$data['published']}', '{$data['author']}', '{$data['report_code']}')";

Comment: I checked the PHPMyAdmin to see whether the new "Descriptions" is updated in the columns or not. It is not there! So should I add it manually?

Comment: I think we did it! I manually added the "descriptions" column in the field list in PHPMyAdmin and it worked! Now I just want to check if it is updating on frontend.

Comment: add a descriptions column in your content table bro.

Comment: Yes! We did it Shoyeb bhai! I cannot thank you enough for your support!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121828/discussion-between-zubair-abbas-and-shoyeb-sheikh).